# Memory Leak from casting with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, casting, reinterpret-cast

I have a strange problem using reinterpret_cast. The following code will lead to a memory leak:

```
template< class T >
static T chunk_cast( unsigned char* p_data ) 
{
    return *( reinterpret_cast< T* >( p_data ) );
}
```

Only POD Types are used with this function. If I comment this function out the memory leak will be gone. So I am sure that this will cause the memory leak. I am using Visual Studio 2012. 
Thank you!

Here is more context:
The function is called from here:

```
prop = PropertyFactory::NewProperty< unsigned char >( Keys::data, chunk_cast< unsigned char >( p_chunk->data ) );
```

And Property here:

```
template< class T >
static PropertyPtr NewProperty( const Type::Key &p_key, T p_value ) {
    PropertyPtr newProp = NewProperty<T>( p_key );
    newProp->setValue( AnyPtr( new boost::any(p_value) ) );
    return newProp;
}
```

AnyPtr and PropertyPtr are std::shared_ptr<>. This will never cause any problems in other usage, only if i am using the casting above. If i am using hard coded values instead of the casting, the memory problem will not occur.

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak?

Comment: If Visual Studio's static analyser reports a leak, then it's a false positive.

Comment: I hardly believe a cast can cause memory leak. However using reinterpret_cast mean, that you did something wrong. It's a timed bomb, never should be used.

Comment: Strange template, don't you think so? `template<class T> static T*` looks much better

Comment: how do you use this function? `p_data` may be leaked but unrelated to this function

Comment: @Melkon, `reinterpret_cast` is extremely helpful and is used frequently through the standard library. If it really is a time bomb, all C++ standard collections are time bombs. I would be careful with blanket statements about it.

Comment: Unless `p_data` is correctly aligned for `T`, this code has undefined behaviour. Other than that, I can't see how it could be leaking memory.

Comment: It will only lead to a memory leak if there is a memory leak in the implementation of `T`. This specific part will not cause it. If you comment this function out the code should not compile, so you're also changing something else.

Comment: @molbdnilo, not returning a value from a function is *merely* undefined behavior. The compiler is not required to catch it.

Comment: if I write a method which returns a pointer as integer by casting and then in the rest of the program I use that *AS INTEGER* it will definitely cause leak

Comment: This is used to retrieve serialized data (only POD's) in a byte stream. I am commenting out the usage of the data and using a standard hard coded value instead of the casting. The memeory leak will occur with a fast growing heap. If I am using default vaules instead of casted values the growing will stop... I dont know it is very strange...
The byte array is deleted correctly after usage.

Comment: We need some context. All we can do now is guessing...

Comment: "If I comment this function out..." shall we assume you also comment out the super-secret *usage* as well as the definition you chose to provide?

Comment: I have added more context information.

Comment: So you are using the function to cast from `unsigned char*` to `unsigned char*`?

Comment: Yes for example, this is done for all POD's for example:
    prop = PropertyFactory::NewProperty< unsigned long >( Keys::data, chunk_cast< unsigned long >( p_chunk->data ) );

Comment: this is about the worst possible way to retrieve serialized data

Comment: @zneak It's pretty much required to catch calls to undefined functions, such as those that have been commented out.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I interpreted it as "if I comment out the function body".